# Optimize MySQL query - Data fetching form views table and Main table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am fetching data from MySQL views table and Main table. I have created Indexes and Primary keys in Main table but I cannot create Indexes and primary keys on views table.

When I execute the below query it is taking around 10 seconds. I want to optimize the below query to less time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `Emp_No`, `Name`
FROM
    `ResLookup`
WHERE
    `IsActive` = 1
        AND `Department` IN ('SDG' , 'HDD', 'ENG', 'PDN')
        AND (`Emp_No` IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            ProjList.PM_No
        FROM
            ProjList
        WHERE
            ProjList.PM_No != 1749 UNION SELECT DISTINCT
            ProjList.PL_No
        FROM
            ProjList
        WHERE
            ProjList.PL_No != 1749)
        OR Emp_No IN (SELECT 
            MEMBER_ID
        FROM
            s_group_details
        WHERE
            GROUP_ID = 'GRP109'
                AND MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL = 30));
```

Only s_group_details table have Indexes and primary key. Remaining all tables are fetching from views table.

Using Explain Query I have the below output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your query requirements but still check below query helpful or not

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `Emp_No`, `Name`
FROM
    `ResLookup` inner join (SELECT DISTINCT
            ProjList.PM_No ,ProjList.PL_No
        FROM
            ProjList
        WHERE
            ProjList.PM_No != 1749 
            or
            ProjList.PL_No != 1749) a
            on ResLookup.Emp_No = a.PM_No
            and ResLookup.Emp_No = a.PL_No
            OR Emp_No IN (SELECT 
            MEMBER_ID
        FROM
            s_group_details
        WHERE
            GROUP_ID = 'GRP109'
                AND MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL = 30)
WHERE
    `IsActive` = 1
        AND `Department` IN ('SDG' , 'HDD', 'ENG', 'PDN');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to turn things somewhat inside-out:

```
SELECT  `Emp_No`, 
        ( SELECT  Name
            FROM  ResLookup
            WHERE  Emp_No = u.PM_No 
        ) AS Name
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  PM_No FROM  ProjList WHERE  PM_No != 1749 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT  PL_No FROM  ProjList WHERE  PL_No != 1749 )
        UNION DISTINCT  
        ( SELECT  MEMBER_ID
            FROM  s_group_details AS d
            WHERE  d.GROUP_ID = 'GRP109'
              AND  d.MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL = 30 
        ) AS u
    JOIN  `ResLookup` AS r  ON u.PM_No = r.Emp_No
    WHERE  r.`IsActive` = 1
      AND  r.`Department` IN ('SDG' , 'HDD', 'ENG', 'PDN');
```

Indexes needed:

```
ResLookup:  (Emp_No, IsActive, Department)
s_group_details:  (GROUP_ID, MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL, MEMBER_ID)
```